# styling dynamic content in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I know there are similar kind of questions asked and answered as well. But my problem is different. Here is code sample that I am using to load and stylize my content.

```
 $("body").on("click","[data-view]",function(){
        var view=$(this).attr("data-view");
        $("#mainView").load("pageRouter.php?view="+view).trigger("create");

    });
```

I searched forums and found `.trigger("create")` is the way to stylize the dynamically loaded content.But it is not helping.

Comment: Just figured it out...

    $("body").on("click","[data-view]",function(){
            var view=$(this).attr("data-view");
            $("#mainView").load("pageRouter.php?view="+view,function(){
                $("#mainView").trigger("create")
             });
    
        });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

You are doing it incorrectly, load is asynchronous function so you need to wait for it to load the content before you can enhance the content.

You will need to do this:

```
$("#mainView").load("pageRouter.php?view="+view, function() {
   $(this).trigger("create");
});
```

This will work if you are only loading content but if you are loading a full page, with header and footer then use this:

```
$("#mainView").load("pageRouter.php?view="+view, function() {
   $(this).trigger("pagecreate");
});
```

Read more about lead and its callback **[here](http://api.jquery.com/load/)**.

### Working example:

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>    
        <script>
            $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){ 
                $("#index").load("load.php", function() {
                    $(this).trigger("pagecreate");
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="index">

        </div>    
    </body>
</html>
```

**load.php**

```
<div data-theme="b" data-role="header">
    <h1>Index page</h1>
</div>

<div data-role="content">
    <a data-role="button">Button</a>
</div>
```